# .each iterates over empty collection - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I've got a polymorphic model called `Attachment`. I'm using the gem Carrierwave to save attachments.

on my `Customer` edit page, I execute the following code:

```
    puts @customer.attachments.count
    @customer.attachments.each do |i|
        puts i.id #outputs a blank line 
    end
```

`puts @customer.attachments.count` outputs `0`. However, the iterator still runs 1 time over attachments and prints out a blank line in place of `puts i.id`.

Here is my model:

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
    mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader # Tells rails to use this uploader for this model.
    validates :name, presence: true

    belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :account
end
```

Comment: count uses sql, what if you use `.size` - does that show 1?  if so, it's in memory and not persisted yet

Comment: `.size` shows 1. However, `Attachment.all.size` shows 0. There shouldn't be any attachments in the db. None have been created on my test environment. @Anthony

Comment: if this is a test, share it.  you don't have any in the database, it's only in memory.  try `@customer.attachments.first.persisted?` it will show false

Comment: the attachments are in memory then and that's why no `id` is outputting (not persisted to db). trying changing it to `puts i.inspect`

Comment: @joslinm I did that and it explained my error. I had another line of code initializing a new attachment that I did not see that's why it showed in memory and not the database. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget that since Ruby 1.9 was released in 2007 the `polymorphic: true` notation has been supported. This is more in line with how other languages handle "dictionary" type structures and as it's less verbose it's worth using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Models will load their associations once, such as `@customer.attachments`, and then not query them again. If the association changes, `@customer.attachments` will be out of date. For example...

```
# Let's say this includes Attachment 123
puts @customer.attachments

Attachment.delete(123)

# Will still include Attachment 123
puts @customer.attachments
```

You can manually unload the association with [`@customer.attachments.reset`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-reset) forcing it to be reloaded next time. Better is to change the association in a manner which the association is aware of, such as calling [`destroy` on the association itself](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-destroy).

```
@customer.attachments.destroy( Attachment.find(123) )
```

This will both delete Attachment 123 and remove it from `@customer.attachments`.

Similar issues with creating an association. This will both create the Attachment and update `@customer.attachments`.

```
puts @customer.attachments

Attachment.create( foo: "bar", customer: @customer )

# will not be aware of the new Attachment.
puts @customer.attachments
```

As before, call `create` on the association.

```
@customer.attachments.create( foo: "bar" )
```

This also has the nice effect of filling in the correct customer for you, avoiding a possible bug. And it avoids repeating the attachment class name all over the code making the code DRY.